# Why is the Ubuntu Touch browser reloading the web pages each time I select the tab?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have noticed that Ubuntu Touch default browser does not keep open web pages and reload the each I switch from one tab to another.

Why is it so? Should I fill a bug report?

Comment: It is annoying indeed. You may want to try the 'Liri Browser' from the app store. I still has some issues of it's own but at least it doesn't reload every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my bq tablet as well. Turns out it was caused by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1576639), which describes how the system "*decides if it should close existing ones based on level of free memory available in the system.*". This wasn't working very well, which is why it needed to reload every tab when switching. The bug should be fixed in OTA11.

After installing OTA11 on my tablet, it works a lot smoother than it did.. :-)

Really cool to see the system improving with every OTA update.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, my tablet is also updated to OTA11... Let's see if it keep improving with the next release.

Comment: The bug says fix released but I am still getting the issue on both my phone and tablet. The default browser refreshes every single time I open a new tab. This is rathet anoying and I should imagine uses both internet allowance and therefore battery. This still needs to be looked into as it is not really fixed.