# Ubuntu Touch - Default browser refreshing

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How do I stop the default browser in my Ubuntu Touch devices from auto refreshing very time I leave and then return to the page? Sometimes it is useful like news sites, bit on othwrs say if I am half way through reading it, it is not that good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/786075/why-is-the-ubuntu-touch-browser-reloading-the-web-pages-each-time-i-select-the-t#comment1180720_786075

Comment: It does look like the same issue, bit I do not feel the bug listed has addressed tje underline issue. I still have this issue every time I open the browser tabs.